# Laravel auto-creating slug not working with factory

Tags: laravel

On my Post model I use a `Slug` trait as below, so that I can re-use this across models:

```php
trait Slug
{
    protected static function bootSlug()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->slug = str()->slug($model->name);
        });

        static::updating(function ($model) {
            $model->slug = str()->slug($model->name);
        });
    }
}
```

Then in my Post Factory I use

`'slug' => str()->slug($word),`

But this doesn't seed the slug value. If I remove the `Slug` trait from the model this works, but it seems that these `creating` and `updating` methods are not called when running the factory. What's the best approach for this?

Comment: Can you include the factory that there is problems with?

Comment: It’s in the post, the part 'slug' => str()->slug($word) is not working (also when I don’t define slug at all) because creating and updating apparently are not called when using a factory.